# Using set_intersection with dynamic allocation?

Tags: c++, dynamic, allocation

I'm reading about `set_intersection` and it appears to expect the user to allocate the correct amount of space (or more) in advance but isn't that strange? In c++ you often use `std::vector` which dynamically allocates space on the go. Why would `set_intersection` implicitly require allocation of space in advance when it is clearly more effective to allocate based on the resulting data size (dynamically)? Is it in hope to maximize performance when the intersection size is known in advance? What about the common case where there intersection size is not known?

Is there any "magical way" to directly allocate one slot per element added to the vector?

Comment: I guess the actual question is `What is an OutputIterator and how do I use one with set_intersection`.

Comment: @pmr
Yes, had I know the `OutputIterator` is the meaningful item in this solution. I'd say the question points towards that question but without requiring the specifity of knowing of an `OutputIterator` to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and it appears to expect the user to allocate the correct amount of space (or more) in advance

No, it doesn't (unless I misunderstood what you're asking):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    //vectors to intersect
    std::vector<int> first{1,2,4,3,8,6,7,5};
    std::vector<int> second{3,15,4,16,36};
    //they need to be sorted 
    std::sort(first.begin(), first.end()); //{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
    std::sort(second.begin(), second.end()); //{3,4,15,16,36}

    //intersection result
    std::vector<int> intersection;

    //intersecting
    std::set_intersection(first.begin(), first.end(),
                          second.begin(), second.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(intersection));

    //output: 3,4
    for(int n : intersection)
        std::cout << n << ",";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very useful :D `back_inserter` is all that was needed.